# Merge vector of vectors into a single vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

I have vector of vectors of T:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> vector_of_vectors_of_T;
```

I want to merge all of them into single vector of T:

```
std::vector<T> vector_of_T;
```

I am currently using this method:

```
size_t total_size{ 0 };
for (auto const& items: vector_of_vectors_of_T){
    total_size += items.size();
}
vector_of_T.reserve(total_size);
for (auto const& items: vector_of_vectors_of_T){
    vector_of_T.insert(end(vector_of_T), begin(items), end(items));
}
```

Is there more straightforward method? Like a ready std function? If not, is there more efficient way to do it manually?

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Luca Pizzamiglio  Thanks for correcing

Comment: @Default i had a doubt about this before asking.. but since I am asking about an std way of doing it. it could also fit here...

Comment: `vector_of_vectors_of_T.SelectMany(...` -- oh wait, wrong language :P

Comment: I guess, I just think it would generate more feedback there. We'll see :) I guess if you're not happy with potential answers here, you could visit CR instead.

Comment: @CompuChip That is too Luxury for C++ :D

Comment: @Humam You could use this for the `reserve` part if you want to get too much STL: `vector_of_T.reserve(std::accumulate(std::begin(vector_of_vectors_of_T), std::end(vector_of_vectors_of_T), 0, [](size_t size, std::vector<T> const& vec) { return size + vec.size(); }));`

Comment: There's not much room for improvement here, other than using move iterators (if you no longer need the original). This is `action::join` in range-v3, so you might see it in the standard...one day.

Comment: I once wrote this [recursive iterator](https://github.com/wassup-/recursive-iterator) library, you may or may not find it useful.

Comment: @CompuChip: Which language would that be? C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a nice exercise to try and write up a generic `join`. The code below takes a nested container `R1<R2<T>` and returns a joined container `R1<T>`. Note that because of the allocator parameters in the Standard Library, this is a bit cumbersome. No attempt is being made to check for allocator compatibility etc.

Fortunately, there's `action::join` function in the upcoming range-v3 library by Eric Niebler, that is quite robust already and works today on Clang:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

// quick prototype
template<template<class, class...> class R1, template<class, class...> class R2, class T, class... A1, class... A2>
auto join(R1<R2<T, A2...>, A1...> const& outer)
{
    R1<T, A2...> joined;
    joined.reserve(std::accumulate(outer.begin(), outer.end(), std::size_t{}, [](auto size, auto const& inner) {
        return size + inner.size();
    }));
    for (auto const& inner : outer)
        joined.insert(joined.end(), inner.begin(), inner.end());
    return joined;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };

    // quick prototype
    std::vector<int> w = join(v);
    std::copy(w.begin(), w.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",")); std::cout << "\n";

    // Eric Niebler's range-v3
    std::vector<int> u = ranges::action::join(v);
    std::copy(u.begin(), u.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ",")); std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b71b17d5682b4657)

Comment: BTW, the mathematical term for such “joinable containers” is [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29). (The concept is rather more general than anything you can write with iterators.)

Answer (score 10):

Using `back_inserter` and `move`;

```
size_t total_size{ 0 };
for (auto const& items: vector_of_vectors_of_T){
    total_size += items.size();
}

vector_of_T.reserve(total_size);
for (auto& items: vector_of_vectors_of_T){    
    std::move(items.begin(), items.end(), std::back_inserter(vector_of_T));
}
```

Instead of `copying`, `std::move` gives it a bit performance enhancement.

Comment: without benchmarking and from abstract point of view, should it be faster that mine? and does it need reserv before it too ?

Comment: This may well be less efficient than the range insert version with move iterators, especially for trivially copyable element types (for which the range insert is likely to be heavily optimized).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could try `std::merge`/`std::move` used in a loop - that are already existing std algorithms. Don't know if that's faster.